# How to sort a list of objects with python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of objects look like below:

```
[{'id': 17L,
  'price': 0,
  'parent_count': 2},
 {'id': 39L,
  'price': 0,
  'parent_count': 1},
 {'id': 26L,
  'price': 2.0,
  'parent_count': 4},
 {'id': 25L,
  'price': 2.0,
  'parent_count': 3}]
```

I want to sort the objects by `'parent_count'` in order to look like this:

```
 [{'id': 39L,
   'price': 0,
   'parent_count': 1},
  {'id': 17L,
   'price': 0,
   'parent_count': 2},
  {'id': 25L,
   'price': 2.0,
   'parent_count': 3},
  {'id': 26L,
   'price': 2.0,
   'parent_count': 4}]
```

Does anyone know a function?

Comment: Is 'parent_count' an optional key? The first object above has 'parent_say', not 'parent_count'?

Comment: i have edited the question. im sorry i wrote it wrong. there is no 'parent_say' key.

Answer (score 12):

Use `operator.itemgetter("parent_count")` as `key` parameter to `list.sort()`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
my_list.sort(key=itemgetter("parent_count"))
```

Comment: This will raise a `KeyError` on the object that has 'parent_say' in place of 'parent_count'. If 'parent_count' is optional `itemgetter()` will need to be replaced with a callable that will return a suitable default value instead of raising KeyError.

Comment: @RobCowie: I will assume for now this was a typo – let's wait what the OP says.

Comment: @RobCowie It's a consistent typo if it is (being both in source and output data)

Comment: sorry man i wrote it wrong. all of them are 'parent_count'. there is no 'parent_say'.

Comment: @ErenSüleymanoğlu: As do all mutating methods in Python.  It sorts the list in place.

Comment: @ErenSüleymanoğlu shame about the typo - I thought my `keygetter` function might have had some use :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use this method:

```
a = [{'id': 17L, 'price': 0, 'parent_count': 2}, {'id': 18L, 'price': 3, 'parent_count': 1}, {'id': 39L, 'price': 1, 'parent_count': 4}]
sorted(a, key=lambda o: o['parent_count'])
```

Result:

```
[{'parent_count': 1, 'price': 3, 'id': 18L}, {'parent_count': 2, 'price': 0, 'id': 17L}, {'parent_count': 4, 'price': 1, 'id': 39L}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have "parent_say" *and* "parent_count"?

```
def get_parent(item):
    return item.get('parent_count', item['parent_say'])
    # return item.get('parent_count', item.get('parent_say')) if missing keys should just go to the front and not cause an exception

my_list.sort(key=get_parent)
```

**or a bit more generic**

```
def keygetter(obj, *keys, **kwargs):
    sentinel = object()
    default = kwargs.get('default', sentinel)
    for key in keys:
        value = obj.get(key, sentinel)
        if value is not sentinel:
            return value
    if default is not sentinel:
        return default
    raise KeyError('No matching key found and no default specified')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x:x["parent_count"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('parent_count'))
```

which doesn't require `operator.itemgetter` and doesn't cause an error if the key doesn't exist (those that don't have the key get put at the start).

Comment: @ErenSüleymanoğlu it is an in-place sort. if you want a sorted copy, use the `sorted` builtin with the same args (but with the list `my_list` as the first arg)